# Updating variables in a for loop

Tags: c++

I am writing an algorithm to do Gaussian elimination. I do not know why the elements of the matrix do not change after the calculations. I think I might need to defined the elements in a different way, but I do not know how. Is there any other easy way to fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, k;
    float mult;

    cout << "Enter the number of equations\n";
    cin >> n;

    int a[n][n], x[n], b[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout << "A[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]=";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "b[" << i+1 << "] is ";
        cin >> a[i][n];
    }


    for (j = 0; j< n; j++)
        for (i=j+1; i< n ; i++)
            mult = a[i][j] / a[j][j];
            for (k = j+1; k < n ; k++)
                a[i][k] = a[i][k] - mult * a[j][k];

    x[n-1] = a[n-1][n]/ a[n-1][n-1];
    for (i = n-2; i=0; i--)
        for (j=n-1; j = i+1; j--)
            a[i][n] = a[i][n] - a[i][j]*x[j];
        x[i] = a[i][n] / a[i][i];
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a minimal example of input, actual and expected output.

Comment: `a[i][n]` and `a[n-1][n]` have undefined behaviour. Fix your indexing.

Comment: You never use `b` for anything. That *might* be an issue... (Enable more warnings in your compiler.)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `std::vector` instead of arrays. Especially that arrays do not support setting size in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with your code:

## VLAs<sup>1</sup> are not standard c++

In standard c++ `int a[n][n], x[n], b[n];` is not valid, because `n` is not constant at compile time. Even if some compilers allow this, don't use it. Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

## The last line of code is not part of any loop

You should use an IDE or simple Editor to fix intendation for you, then you would see, that the last line `x[i] = a[i][n] / a[i][i];` is not part of any loop. My tip: *always* use parantheses after `for`!

## The last loops have a wrong condition

The condition of the last loop `for(i = n-2; i=0; i--)` is `i=0`. This will_assign_ the value 0 to `i` then evaluate `i` as condition and since `i` is zero it will exit the loop. Probably you meant to use `==` to *compare* the values.

The same thing goes for the nested loop `for (j=n-1; j = i+1; j--)`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Variable Length Arrays

<sup>2</sup> Actually this loop will run forever for any `n != 0`